# How to set a serializer field as not required in django rest framwork?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want the `story_media` field to be optional when a story is created. This means that it is up to the user to add some media to a story or not. But if I submit the data without the `story_media` field, I get the error that `story_media` is required.

I followed the approach from the Django [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#additional-keyword-arguments) and added `extra_kwargs = {'story_media': {'required': False}}` as keyword argument. However, the error message remains.

```
## Story_Media Model
class Story_Media (models.Model):
    story = models.ForeignKey(Story,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name = 'story_media', related_query_name = 'story_media')
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='story_media/', blank=True, null=True, validators=[validate_file_extension_image])
    isTitlePicture = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True) 

## Story_Media Serializer
class Story_Media_Serializer (serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Story_Media
        fields =  ('id','isTitlePicture', 'file',)
    

class StoryCreateUpdateSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer):
    story_media = Story_Media_Serializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Story
        fields =  ('title','description', 'place', 'audio','story_media', 'language', )
        extra_kwargs = {'story_media': {'required': False}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        current_user = self.context["request"].user
        story_media = validated_data.pop('story_media')


        story_instance = Story.objects.create(author=current_user, **validated_data)

        for img in story_media:
            Story_Media.objects.create(**img, story=story_instance)
                    
        return story_instance
```

Comment: In your models.py, have you set the field as blank=True, null=True ?

Comment: @BriseBalloches thanks for answer, yes i have the set the fileds in the model according to your suggestion. I added my model to the post.

Comment: And with the serializer field like this : `story_media = Story_Media_Serializer(many=True, required=False, allow_null=True)` ?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you need to add is in your `models.py` file;

```
story_media = models.CharField(max_length=..., blank=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In my case story_media is a own model. I added the model and serializer in my post.

Comment: Does that mean you want to add the functionality of keeping the whole table or model empty if a user wants to?

Comment: exactly there is no instance of story_media created in case the user adds no story_media to the story.